# Shell scripting for file formatting purpose

Tags: python-3.x, bash, shell, file, analysis

Input File 1

```
1 2
3 4
```

Input File 2

```
5
6
7
```

Output File

```
1 2 5
1 2 6
1 2 7
3 4 5
3 4 6
3 4 7
```

How could I achieve the above by simple shell scripting?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in your post and let us know then.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your use case, consider [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/):

```
parallel echo {} :::: input_file_1  :::: input_file_2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using bash this is an option ( while read )

```
$ cat test1.txt
1 2
3 4
$ cat test2.txt
5
6
7
$ while read -r line;
> do
> while read -r line2
> do
> var=$(echo $line $line2)
> echo $var
> done < test2.txt
> done < test1.txt
1 2 5
1 2 6
1 2 7
3 4 5
3 4 6
3 4 7
$
```